# Regular expression test not working properly

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a simple RegExp that would validate a login name:

```
function _validateLogin( login ) {
   //This should allow for [a-zA-Z0-9_] as well as '.' and '@'
   //Spaces are not allowed
   var re = /[\w\.@]+/;
   return re.test( login );
}
```

But for some reason it returns `true` even if I give it `'aa aa'`.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to **[`^[\w.@]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/lK0gY4/1)** to match with entire string. I case `aa aa` it will return true , since `aa` will match . So use `^` at beginning for assert position at beginning of a string and `$` at end for assert position at end of the string. Also there is no need for escape `.`, since dot doesn't have any have special meaning inside a character class.

```js
function _validateLogin(login) {
  //This should allow for [a-zA-z0-9_] as well as '.' and '@'
  //Spaces are not allowed
  var re = /^[\w.@]+$/;
  return re.test(login);
}

console.log(_validateLogin('aa aa'));
console.log(_validateLogin('aaaa'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not anchoring the regex. It will return true for any string that contains a letter, digit, underscore, dot, or at sign anywhere.

Fix: `var re = /^[\w.@]+$/;`